# C++ mixing static and dynamic linking (Msys2 Qt)

Tags: python, c++, qt, static, linker-flags

I'm using MSyS2 for developing Qt/C++ programs which works very well. I now ran into the problem that static linking does not work because Python (which I use within my code) does not provide a static library (only a shared one). I tracked the error down to the created makefile which contains the linker switch:

```
-static
```

I figured out that removing it and adding

```
-Bdynamic -lpython3.5 -Bstatic
```

does what I want: link everything statically except the Python parts. The problem is as soon as i rerun qmake for the project my changes will be overwritten. I found no solution to get rid of the "-static", it seems to be added by qmake and cannot be removed by the .pro file.

Is there a solution to get rid of the "-static" switch?

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS -= -static
```

does not work unfortunately :-(.

Win7 Pro 64bit, Qt5.5, Mingw GCC 5.3.0, Python 3.5.0

Comment: I was under the impression that Qt by default builds *dynamically* and that linking *statically* opens you up to all the issues of the LGPL license that Qt is distributed under. I'm not sure why you therefore have the -static flag by default..

Comment: I think the flag does come with the package mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-static package which also adds the compiler kit "static" to my Qt Creator setup

Comment: Did you try hardcode the complete library within ``LIBS += mySharedLib.so``?

Comment: I just tried it without any result. Tried: `LIBS += -llibpython3.5m.dll.a` , `LIBS += -lpython3.5` , `LIBS += -llibpython3.5m.dll`. BTW: `LIBS += -lpython3.5` works when compiling everything with shared objects/dynamically linked. That's the way I already use to get it compiling for dynamic linking. But not a solution for static. The error is always: `:-1: Error: cannot find -llibpython3.5m.dll.a` just replace the name+extensions of the lib that was used in the .pro file.

Comment: You should use `LIBS += -lpython3.5m`

Comment: Either `LIBS += lpython3.5` or `LIBS += lpython3.5m` does work to find the library when compiling everything with shared libraries. But as soon as I switch to static compiling (by selecting the Kit: Desktop Qt (static) MinGW-w64 64bit (MSYS2)) the libraries cannot be found. So its good to know to use `-lpython3.5m` but it does not solve my problem.